# R Shiny: Cylce the class of an actionButton on click

Tags: r, shiny

I'd like to have an actionButton that cycles its class between "btn-success", "btn-warning", "btn-danger" based on the button click. Unfortunately I can't seem to figure out how to get that value into the class argument of the actionButton.

```
library(shiny)

v <- reactiveValues(btn_status = "btn-secondary")

ui <- fluidPage(

# Application title
titlePanel("Change Button Color on click"),


# Create an action button that cycles through 3 bootstrap colors and can be reset
mainPanel(
    actionButton("run","L", class = isolate(v$btn_status)),
    actionButton("reset", "Clear"), 
    textOutput("status"),
)

)

server <- function(input, output) {

observeEvent(input$run, {
    v$btn_status <- "btn-success"
})    

observeEvent(input$reset, {
    v$btn_status <- "NULL"

})  

output$status <- renderText({
    v$btn_status
})

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You say that `btn_status` can be one of "btn-success", "btn-warning", "btn-danger". But the reset button sets `btn_status` to "NULL". So is "NULL" also allowed as a status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to do (see my comment above); but I *think* you're after something like this:

```r
library(shiny)

valid_status <- c("btn-success", "btn-warning", "btn-danger")

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Change Button Color on click"),
    mainPanel(
        uiOutput("statusButton"),
        actionButton("reset", "Clear"),
        textOutput("status"),
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    v <- reactiveValues(button_idx = 1)
    get_button_idx <- reactive(v$button_idx)

    output$statusButton <- renderUI({
        idx <- get_button_idx()
        actionButton("run", "L", class = valid_status[idx])
    })

    observeEvent(input$run, {
        v$button_idx <- ifelse(v$button_idx < 3, v$button_idx + 1, 1)
    })

    observeEvent(input$reset, {
        v$button_idx <- 1
    })

    output$status <- renderText({
        valid_status[v$button_idx]
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

producing

[image]

The key is to use a `reactive` value within `renderUI` to update the `class` of the `actionButton`. To align the buttons you could use `fluidRow` if necessary.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Sorry for being less than in my explanation. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Now that I've had a chance to sit down with it, I have one question. Why is it necessary to store "get_button_idx" and then pass "get_button_idx()" to "idx" in order to use it as an index? It seems to work if I just call v$button_idx, but I'm assuming there is some best practice that would be violating. Thanks again!